# R Shiny not randomizing

Tags: r, random, shiny

I am trying to write a Shiny app for a class I'm teaching that draws a random sample from a dataset and computes summary statistics. Whenever I press the reset button on the UI, a new subset should be sampled. Here is my code so far:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

# Output for Ch. 1 Problems: Central Tendency

# Prepare data
observeEvent(input$Ch1.Prob.CT.reset, {
    Ch1.Prob.CT.n <- sample(8:12, 1)
    Ch1.Prob.CT.obs <- sample(1:nrow(cars), Ch1.Prob.CT.n)
})
data <- eventReactive(input$Ch1.Prob.CT.reset, {
    cars[Ch1.Prob.CT.obs, 'dist', drop=F]
})

# Outputs
output$Ch1.Prob.CT.Data <- renderDataTable({
    data()
})

output$Ch1.Prob.CT.Mean.out <- renderUI({
    if (is.na(input$Ch1.Prob.CT.Mean.in)) { # Error checking
        p("No answer provided")
    } else if (round(input$Ch1.Prob.CT.Mean.in, digits = 4) == round(mean(Ch1.Prob.CT.data[,1]), digits = 4)) {
        p("Correct", style = "color:green")
    } else {
        p("Incorrect", style = "color:red")
    }
})
})
```

The problem is that the sample is not random; it is always the same, every time. Even when I press the reset button, the sample is exactly the same as the one before.

Why is Shiny not randomizing? And how can I make it randomize again?

Comment: It is not recommended to use some dots in the names of the shiny elements (eg. use `Ch1_Prob_CT_reset` instead of `Ch1.Prob.CT.reset`)

Comment: Moreover, I have not used Shiny from a long time so I'm not really sure, but I would try to set `Ch1.Prob.CT.obs` in the `data` reactive element, *not* in the observer. If you want to update it in the observer, you should use a reactive variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such code:

```
observeEvent(input$xxx, {
 x <- ...
})
f <- eventReactive(input$xxx, {
 [do something with x] 
})
```

does not work.

You can simply remove the observer and do:

```
f <- eventReactive(input$xxx, {
 x <- ...
 [do something with x] 
})
```

If you want to use a variable subject to modifications inside an observer, you have to use a *reactive list*, like this :

```
values <- reactiveValues()
values$x <- [initial value of x]
observeEvent(input$xxx, {
 values$x <- ...
})
```

(In addition, don't use some dots (`.`) in the names of the shiny elements.)

Answer (score 1):

Add a line such as

```
set.seed(as.integer(Sys.time()))
```

before you need random numbers

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with the seed. The problem is simply due to the fact that the "reset button" has no effect on the output.

Comment: I do add this line(as numeric in the case)in https://floatsd.shinyapps.io/GeoCUI/ demo page before a sample command, but it seems doesn't work as I expected.